# Mainbar partly hidden under right sidebar with Firefox 10.0.1

Tags: support, design

Since yesterday the "mainbar" of the website is partly hidden under the right "sidebar" using Firefox 10.0.1 and Win 7 Pro, SP1.

I can bring it back into view by scrolling. Changing the window size has no effect.

Screenshot normal:

[image]

Screen shot after scrolling the mainbar to the left:
[image]

Under Chrome the site works fine.

Comment: Not seeing that. It happens when I (via Firebug) increase the line height of the "Top Questions" header from 34px to 41px, but normally (also Win 7 and FF 10.0.1) it doesn't.

Comment: I barely can see anything in that screenshot, can you provide a bigger one?

Comment: Also, it seems more like your whole question section is shifted to the right.

Comment: @Bobby, I added new screenshots.

Comment: There's an element to the left of/overlapping the list, fire up Firebug and see what that is. Also, I'd try to disable all extensions, and see of that helps.

Comment: @bobby, extensions are not it, and I am not well versed enough with CSS to find the issue. One thing, the moment I leave the landing page, by clicking on a tag for instance, the issue is gone.

Comment: Just click on Firebug, then select the element with the helper, and then show us what you're seeing.

Comment: @bobby I am lost, I can not find a specific lone offending element. So I can not show you anything out of the ordinary. Nor can I spot the difference between the landing page and the correctly functioning question page after you select a tag. And on my Mac, it renders just fine.